# Snap chart to grid or place a chart in a cell?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

Is there a way to snap charts to the grid?

In my spreadsheet, my chart hangs a little below my table, but I would like the chart to expand/contract with the cells on the left.

*If this is an easy answer, I assure you I've spend a decent amount of time searching Google, the documentation, and the spreadsheets themselves*

** *Alternative answers are welcome*

*** Still looking for an answer to this. Even a definite *"not possible"* would be helpful at this point

**Sample Image:** [image: Pie Chart Hangs Below Grid]

Comment: Would love to know this, too, but there doesn't seem to be anything like that...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- as already anticipated, snapping chart to the grid is not possible
- charts can be resized and moved around across the whole sheet to millimetre scope
- position and/or size of charts can't be dynamic
- maximum precision of placing can be achieved by holding **<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>** key with arrow keys
- the only truly dynamic in-cell chart is **`=SPARKLINE()`** chart (any other chart is overlayed over cells)

> [image: 1]
>
> [image: 6]